# Variable defined, but the console says not

Tags: ionic-framework, typescript2.0

It's a simple alertController box, which create a checklist element. When I click on add, the function addCheck() of the class ChecksPage is called :

```
 export class ChecksPage implements OnInit {
  checkList: Check[] = [];

  constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addCheck(){
    this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Nouvelle liste',
      inputs:[{
          name:'nom',
          placeholder: 'Nom'

      }],

      buttons:[
        {
          text: 'Annuler',
          role: 'cancel'
        },

        {
          text: 'Ajouter',
          handler: data => {
            if(typeof data.nom !=null){
              let newCheck: Check;
              newCheck.id = ''+this.checkList.length;
              newCheck.title = data.nom;
              this.checkList.push(newCheck);
            }
          }
      }]
  }).then(alertEl => alertEl.present());
  }

}
```

But, I have an error : the variable newCheck is undefined. Why ?
Check is an interface :

```
    export interface Check{
  id: string;
  title: string;
}
```

Comment: It's not `"let newCheck: Check;"` , it's `"let newCheck = Check;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't init your variable, please do as follow:

```
const newCheck = {
    id: ''+this.checkList.length,
    title: data.nom
} as Check;
```

Comment: OK, works perfectly, visual studio prefers const because newCheck is never reassign, but it works, thank you